# On the Sylow subgroups of a subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

What I am trying to prove: Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$. Then prove that two $p$-sylow of $H$ are contained in different $p$-sylow of $G$.

My attempt was suppose that they are contained in one $p$-sylow of $G$ and trying with the conjugations of $G$ to get it.

I would appreciate some help
Thanks

Comment: Then it holds trivially? Indeed, every distinct p sylow of H are in different p sylow of G (because there is no distinct p sylow of H) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Suppose $P\in\operatorname{Syl}_p(G)$.  What is $P\cap H$?  If $P$ contains $P_1,P_2\in\operatorname{Syl}_p(H)$, what does that tell you?

Comment: Uff!! That is clear! $P \cap H$ is a p-subgroup of $H$ with more elements that the sylows of $H$.